# O365 Mail API using Node as Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, xamarin, office365api

I am writing a O365 Send Mail API using Node. My Node act as a server, Angular and Xamarin  act as client(Web and Mobile). I have gone through the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-sendmail?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=javascript). According to that I have included `Microsoft SDK` and registered my app in `Microsoft Azure` to get `Client ID`. Then here comes the mail API code.

**Code**

```
const options = {
    authProvider,
};

const client = Client.init(options);

const sendMail = {
  message: {
    subject: "Meet for lunch?",
    body: {
      contentType: "Text",
      content: "The new cafeteria is open."
    },
    toRecipients: [
      {
        emailAddress: {
          address: "fannyd@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"
        }
      }
    ],
    ccRecipients: [
      {
        emailAddress: {
          address: "danas@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  saveToSentItems: "false"
};

let res = await client.api('/me/sendMail')
    .post(sendMail);
```

To Create `authProvider`, I have to scenarios here

1. Web App that calls web APIs
2. Mobile app that calls web APIs

I have no idea how to create `authProvider`. The documentation is confusing. Can someone help me out

Comment: Mostly It's placed on backend side

Comment: This looks like front end code https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-javascript/blob/dev/docs/CustomAuthenticationProvider.md

Answer (score 1):

You need to put that code in your backend (`node.js`). Just make a dynamic helper function for sending a mail  like this

**utils.js**

```
const options = {
  authProvider,
};

const client = Client.init(options);

const utils = {};

utils.sendMail = async (to, subject, body, cc, isSave) => {
  const mailOptions = {
    message: {
      subject: subject || '',
      body: { ...body },
      toRecipients: to,
    },
    saveToSentItems: `${isSave}`,
  };
  if (cc) {
    mailOptions.message.ccRecipients = cc;
  }
  const result = await client.api('/me/sendMail').post(mailOptions);
  return result;
};

module.exports = utils;
```

And calling that function like this

```
const test = async () => {
  try {
    const to = [
      {
        emailAddress: {
          address: 'fannyd@contoso.onmicrosoft.com',
        },
      },
    ];
    const cc = [
      {
        emailAddress: {
          address: 'danas@contoso.onmicrosoft.com',
        },
      },
    ];
    const subject = 'Test';
    const body = {
      contentType: 'Text',
      content: 'The new cafeteria is open.',
    };
    const saveToSentItems = true;
    const result = await utils.sendMail(to, subject, body, cc, saveToSentItems);
    return result;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    throw err;
  }
};

test();
```

I suggest you put your logic in the backend When you have multiple clients such as  `android`, `iOs`, `PWA` then you need to rewrite your code in all 3 platforms, If you put your common business logic to the backend then a single code can serve to all 3 platforms.

Comment: That's great and helpful. But I have doubt with authProvider. Documentation was confusing for me

Comment: and what's your doubt?

Comment: What is `authProvider ?`  It has been specified in `options`. How to create authProvider ?

Comment: Can you share a doc where you find this

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS